# sql server 2008 query inline

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

`select devicename, name, value, timestamp from table1` gives me the following,

```
DEVICENAME     NAME     VALUE    TIMESTAMP
123            CURRENT  130      2012-10-16 13:00:00.000
123            AVG      140      2012-10-16 13:00:00.000
123            MIN      100      2012-10-16 13:00:00.000
123            MAX      160      2012-10-16 13:00:00.000
```

How do i get them like this in sql query,

```
123, 130, 140, 100, 160 2012-10-16 13:00:00.000
```

Comment: Did you want that output as a comma-separated list (which is what you show), or separate columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
  devicename, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'CURRENT' THEN value ELSE NULL END), 
  MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'AVG' THEN value ELSE NULL END), 
  MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'MIN' THEN value ELSE NULL END), 
  MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'MAX' THEN value ELSE NULL END), 
  timestamp 
from table1
GROUP BY devicename, timestamp
```

Comment: What if i needed the 'CURRENT' value assigned to avg,min, or max if it avg, min, max has null value?

Comment: You could use the pivot example that @bluefeet provided and use Current if those values are `NULL`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `PIVOT` for this if you want this in separate columns:

```
select devicename, [Current], [Avg], [Min], [Max], timestamp
from
(
  select devicename, name, value, timestamp
  from table1
) x
pivot
(
  max(value) 
  for name in ([Current], [Avg], [Min], [Max])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84c19/2)

If you want all of the values in the same column, then you can use the following:

```
select devicename,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + cast(value as varchar(10))
              from table1 t2
              where t1.DEVICENAME = t2.DEVICENAME
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') name,
  timestamp
from table1 t1
group by devicename, timestamp
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/42b2c/5)

Answer (score 0):

you can concatenate them into a column

```
select a + ' '+ b as Column1 from yourtable
```

or return them as an output variable

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.devicename, *
FROM 
    (SELECT devicename, value as 'current', timestamp 
    FROM table1 WHERE name = 'current') x 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT devicename, value as [avg] FROM table1 WHERE name = 'avg') y 
    ON x.devicename = y.devicename
INNER JOIN (SELECT devicename, value as [min] FROM table1 WHERE name = 'min') z 
    ON x.devicename = z.devicename
INNER JOIN (SELECT devicename, value as [max] FROM table1 WHERE name = 'max') q 
    ON x.devicename = q.devicename
```

Answer (score -1):

```
create table table1 (devicename varchar(10)
              ,name varchar(100)
              ,value varchar(10)
              ,TimeSTamp datetime)

INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT '123','CURRENT','130','2012-10-16 13:00:00.000'
UNION
 SELECT '123','AVG','140','2012-10-16 13:00:00.000'
UNION
 SELECT '123','MIN','100','2012-10-16 13:00:00.000'
UNION
 SELECT '123','MAX','160','2012-10-16 13:00:00.000'


select devicename, name, value, timestamp from table1 


SELECT DISTINCT t1.devicename
     , value_list
     , t1.timestamp
  FROM table1 t1
 INNER JOIN (SELECT t2.devicename
                  , t2.timestamp
                  , value_list = SUBSTRING((SELECT t3.value
                                                 + ', '
                                              FROM table1 t3
                                             WHERE t3.devicename = t2.devicename
                                               AND t3.timestamp  = t2.timestamp
                                             ORDER BY t3.value
                                               FOR XML PATH('')),1,LEN((SELECT t3.value
                                                                             + ', '
                                                                          FROM table1 t3
                                                                         WHERE t3.devicename = t2.devicename
                                                                           AND t3.timestamp  = t2.timestamp
                                                                         ORDER BY t3.value
                                                                           FOR XML PATH(''))) -1)
               FROM table1 t2
              GROUP BY t2.devicename
                     , t2.timestamp) t4 on t4.devicename  = t1.devicename
                                       AND t4.timestamp   = t1.timestamp


drop table1
```